# Moving data to correct record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where the data is needs to be corrected.  Below is an example of one record.  Basically the data in the selling closed_unit needs to be in the Agent_to_Agent Ref close_unit.  I have tried every different what I can think of but I can't get it figured out.  I am sure it is fairly simple I think I am just looking too hard at the wrong way.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Current (bad) data:

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
| sale_no | payeeID |      ComType       | close_units |   record_type   | ref_agent_type | referring_agentID | ref_side |
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
|    7586 |    1001 | Listing            |           1 | Listing         | NULL           |                 0 |          |
|    7586 |    2001 | Selling            |           1 | Selling         | NULL           |                 0 |          |
|    7586 |    3254 | NULL               |           0 | Off The Top Ref | NULL           |                 0 | L        |
|    7586 |    4684 | Agent to Agent Ref |           0 | Agent Paid Ref  | Selling        |              2001 |          |
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
| sale_no | payeeID |      ComType       | close_units |   record_type   | ref_agent_type | referring_agentID | ref_side |
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
|    7586 |    1001 | Listing            |           1 | Listing         | NULL           |                 0 |          |
|    7586 |    2001 | Selling            |           0 | Selling         | NULL           |                 0 |          |
|    7586 |    3254 | NULL               |           0 | Off The Top Ref | NULL           |                 0 | L        |
|    7586 |    4684 | Agent to Agent Ref |           1 | Agent Paid Ref  | Selling        |              2001 |          |
+---------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: So, that table there represents the current (bad) status, right? Can you add the expected (good) result?

Comment: Hi thanks for the input I just tried to add an ascii table...I need to move the close_unit of 1 in the selling row to the close_unit of the agent_to_agent row.  Would you update work?

Comment: Edited yout question. Is that the expected result?

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to repaste the table... so the correct out come for the close units column would be 1, 0, 0, 1  from top to bottom.  Sorry I'm a noob to the interface here.

Comment: Refresh the web page and you'll see the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will copy the value to the "Agent to Agent Ref" row:

```
update my_table t1 set close_units = (
  select close_units from my_table t2 
    where t2.sale_no = t1.sale_no and t2.ComType = 'Selling'
  )
  where ComType = 'Agent to Agent Ref';
```

And this one will reset the "Selling" value to zero:

```
update my_table t1 
  set close_units = 0
  where ComType = 'Selling'
    and exists (
      select close_units from my_table t2 
        where t2.sale_no = t1.sale_no and t2.ComType = 'Agent to Agent Ref'
    )
```

Comment: I will give this a try I think I was not using the where clause outside the sub query.    In the sub query could I us... where t2.sale_no = t1.sale_no and t2.ComType = t1.ref_agent_type     As 'Selling' is not alway what will be in that column.  Could be Listing, Rental....

Comment: Getting an error..Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I assummed there would be a single "Selling" row per sale. However, it seems that for the same "sale" (sale_no) you have multiple rows labeled as "Selling". Is that the case? What do you want to do in this case? Pick any of those rows, the total sum, other?

Comment: I was trying to a where clause something like where t1.referring_agentID = t2.payeeID  But I was still getting 0 or NULL